# ASP.Net how to call a method in a controller without redirecting the view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, file-io

I have a view that displays every file that is in a specified folder and a delete button beside the name. I would like for the user to be able to click the button, delete the file from the folder, and then the page refresh with the updated list of files.

**Index.cshtml**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

@{
    var arrayOfDocs = ViewData["arrayOfDocs"] as string[];
}

<h2>Case Log Documents</h2>

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            Files
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in arrayOfDocs)
    {
<tr>
    <td>
        <a href="~/Case_Log_Docs/@item">@item</a>
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { fileName = item })
    </td>
</tr>
    }

</table>
```

With this line I am trying to call the Delete method in my controller  `@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { fileName = item })`. However the action link redirects me to a Delete page (which does not, and will not ever exist). What I want to happen is to call the 'Delete' method and then refresh the page I am on.

**Controller**

```
   [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Delete(string fileName)
        {
            try
            {
                string path = Server.MapPath("~/Case_Log_Docs/");
                string fullPath = path + fileName;
                if (System.IO.File.Exists(fullPath))
                {
                    System.IO.File.Delete(fullPath);
                }

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch
            {
                return View("Index");
            }
        }
```

How can I set this up to do that?

Comment: Hello. Welcome to SO. What is the name of your controller? The one containing the `Delete` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds to me like the route is not being found. You have a few things to work on here.

First, you have marked your method as accepting Http requests with the `POST` verb:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Delete(string fileName)
```

This means the request coming from the front end needs to use `POST` as the verb in order to be routed appropriately. As @jackdraw has mentioned in his answer, you need to use a form in order to accomplish this. Alternatively, you can do an Ajax post but that option seems to be beyond the scope of your question, so enclose your table with a form tag. You have not provided the name of your controller(s), so I will use placeholders:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Delete", "NameOfControllerWithDeleteMethod"))
{
    //Put your table here
}
```

You will also need a field to hold the identifier of what you intend to delete. In this case, the file name itself:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Delete", "NameOfControllerWithDeleteMethod"))
{
    <input type="hidden" id="fileName" name="fileName" />
    //Put your table here
}
```

You will then need to populate this field with the name of the file you intend to delete. You can do so on the `Click` event of the Delete button. Replace your action link with an input of type `submit` and use JS to set it. Inside your loop. Notice the interpolation of JS strings and Razor code:

```
@foreach (var item in arrayOfDocs)
{
<tr>
<td>
    <a href="~/Case_Log_Docs/@item">@item</a>
</td>
<td>
    <input type="submit" value="Delete File" onclick="document.getElementById('fileName').value = '@item';" />
</td>
</tr>
}
```

Lastly, on your controller's `Delete` method you want to redirect back to your original `Index` method on both cases, whether you experienced an error or not. You can use the temporary data collection to pass back a message that only gets shown once:

```
try
{
    string path = Server.MapPath("~/Case_Log_Docs/");
    string fullPath = path + fileName;
    if (System.IO.File.Exists(fullPath))
    {
        System.IO.File.Delete(fullPath);
    }

    TempData["UserMessage"] = "Success!";
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "NameOfControllerWithIndexMethod");
}
catch
{
    TempData["UserMessage"] = "Something went wrong... :-(";
    return RedirectToAction("NameOfControllerWithIndexMethod");
}
```

Collect this data in your view and show it somewhere:

```
@{ var userMessage = TempData["UserMessage"] as string; }
@if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(userMessage))
{
    <div class="some-message-style">@userMessage</div>
}
```

Comment: This is an incredible response, thank you so much for taking the time to type this out. I have 1 last problem though. My controller is named Case_Log_Docs_Controller.cs but when I use this to enclose my table ````@using (Html.BeginForm("Delete", "Case_Log_Docs_Controller"))```` I get an error that it can't find that controller. What am I doing wrong? I also noticed that in other parts of the project, the controller "Case_LogsController.cs" is referenced like this: ````@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Case_Log", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })) ```` I dont get naming?

Comment: Ok apparently just leaving out the word controller works. Thank you so much this works perfectly! I upvoted your post but since I'm so new it doesn't show, but thank you!

Comment: @ColeDOT I am glad I was able to help.